# Why can't I create an empty Pull Request for discussion prior to developing changes?

Tags: git, github

I want to branch from `master` and immediately create an empty Pull Request to discuss implementation details of a specific feature.

After selecting my branch and clicking "Pull Request", Github claims "Nothing to Compare" and doesn't offer any "Create Pull Request" button.

Github's own documentation on Flow [states](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) (click the right-arrow twice):

> You can open a Pull Request **at any point** during the development process: when you have little **or no code** but want to share some screenshots or general ideas, when you're stuck and need help or advice, or when you're ready for someone to review your work.

But their own documentation on Pull Requests [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/) states:

> Pull requests can only be opened if there are differences between your branch and the upstream branch

I would like to utilise Github collaboration features with my team prior to committing changes to code.  As we understand it, Pull Requests are for code changes and discussion of implementation details (ie: the "solution"), while Issues are higher level, for discussing features/bugs (ie: the "problem").

Am I misunderstanding these things?

Edit:

[Apparently](https://superuser.com/questions/328931/why-cant-i-push-an-empty-commit/894128#894128) I can circumvent the process by changing the branch with an empty commit:

> `git commit --allow-empty -m "make pull request"`

but I am trying to better understand why my (default) decision to create an empty PR was wrong in the first place, and why their documentation appears contradictory.  Is there a strict "discuss code *explicitly* in PRs" policy or similar?  Is this a contentious issue?

## Update

Github have released [Draft Pull Requests](https://github.blog/2019-02-14-introducing-draft-pull-requests/), but (alas) they can't be created if the 2 branches are identical.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a GitHub thing and has nothing to do with Git itself.

Comment: @torek Some would say GitHub has a lot to do with git.

Comment: It's the *discussion* part (the conversation and email generation that GitHub does) that's quite unconnected to Git. That's a significant part of how GitHub "adds value", as the marketing-speak goes. If anything this should be helpful to your issue with them, since creating a code-less pull request would mean more "added value", and not being able to do that means less.

Comment: Nice trick with the `--allow-empty`!

Comment: I was looking for a way to create a pull request for a  repository that will serve as the base for other sub-repo but github does not allow it since it require changes between master and this new repository and the --allow-empty help me with it,  thanks you got my up vote on this.

Comment: `--allow-empty` also helped me! Just FYI, you can post an answer to your own post and accept it 

Answer (score 5):

The documentation talking about "no code" dates from... December 2013:

[image]

It is possible they changed their policy in the official documentation, which is up-to-date and apply to `github.com` as well as GitHub Enterprise.
So  you might want to [contact GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) to mention this inaccuracy.

Comment: Interestingly, while I haven't heard back from Github yet, the "Last Updated" on that article is now Nov 30, 2017, and it still claims "little or no code".